# Issue with recyclerview dependency after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dependencies, androidx, recyclerview-layout

I'm completely rebuilding an old project, and have only kept the `xml` files (which show no error). I chose to update to androidx, and have synced all dependencies correctly, except for `recyclerview`. Whenever I try to sync, it would show the error log listed below.

`android:useAndroidX=true` and `android:useJetifier=true` are both set in `gradle.properties` file. No errors were detected in any `xml` file. I triedd Invalidating caches/restarting, rebooting the whole system, and cleaning the project. I actually don't know what else to do.

The error is happening only when I add one or both these dependencies:

```
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

I tried adding and removing each dependency individually. only those produced the error.

*Error*

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0- alpha05.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-alpha05.
 Show Details
 Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


 ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-alpha05.
 Show Details
 Affected Modules: app
```

*build.gradle(app) file:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shababuna"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-alpha05'
}
```

Comment: Check for migration here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: @Venky I already did. Nothing helped there.

Comment: Provide details of gradle properties file @Skullz

Comment: I think you should check which gradle properties do it support. For that libs @Skullz